# Need help with using Crud 1.1 and jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, codeigniter, crud

I found this Crud 1.1 that someone put together on the CI forums and I just edited it so I could query different column names. The problem is when I try to edit a row it seems to be still using the column 'id' in the query. I can't for the life of me figure out what could be referencing that column name.

Has anyone used this [template](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/157452/) to do something similar?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a stupid question but have you done a "search in files" for the value "id" in the CRUD folder structure? I'm sure its there and you just missed it..

This approach would at least track down the `ID` element.  Keep in mind modifying this library in this fashion will cause greater headaches when/if you want to update to a never version (when it comes out that is).